# ASP.NET core 3.1 warning while running Identity scripts on SQL Server 2016,2017

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am trying to run ASP.NET Core identity scripts on my database from the scripts generated by migrations. But I am getting below warning on SQL Server 2016 and 2017 management console.

> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_sfr_user_logins' has maximum length of 1800 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
>
> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_sfr_user_roles' has maximum length of 1800 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
>
> Warning! The maximum key length for a clustered index is 900 bytes. The index 'PK_sfr_user_tokens' has maximum length of 2700 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

This warning is caused by below script due to primary key size exceeds 900 bytes.

```
CREATE TABLE [sfr_user_logins] 
(
    [LoginProvider] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderDisplayName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [UserId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_sfr_user_logins] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([LoginProvider], [ProviderKey]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_sfr_user_logins_sfr_users_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [sfr_users] ([Id]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Has anybody else faced the problem like this before? Why did Microsoft team decide to have that long primary key? If I am to resize the field size then what should be the proper length?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary key/Foreign key max size is 900 bytes. 
In your table, PK column is 450 characters long, hovewer each unicode charcter (nvarchar) could take from 1 to 4 bytes depending on data.

- First 127 characters (ASCII-US) have 1 bytes per char
- Latin, greek, cyrylic, hebrew, some other alphabets - max 2 bytes per character
- Chinese, Japanese and Korean characters - max 3 bytes per character
- Some special characters - up to 4 bytes per char

So you program will work fine for european languages, but there will be insert error for record of 450 Koren characters.

224 (900 / 4) characters max won't have that problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue. But how do you solve this problem. And why asp.net core program has this problem for the generated column?

Comment: It's just a warning to you as a developer that on some input data error is possible, column should be generated anyway.

Comment: Yes, columns are generated but ignoring the warning on production site may be fatal. I fixed the issue by reducing the column size. If you know any idea on right length then let me know. Thanks